# Oozie command to rerun workflow with skip nodes not working

Tags: oozie

There is a couple of options while re-running a workflow via Oozie command line.

1. oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes
2. oozie.wf.rerun.skip.nodes

Option 1 works fine, however, while re-running workflow with option 2, it throws error E0404.

`oozie job -oozie http://<url>/oozie -Doozie.wf.rerun.skip.nodes=node1,node2 -rerun WFID`

**Error: E0404 : E0404: Only one of the properties are allowed [oozie.wf.rerun.skip.nodes OR oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes]**

However, below works fine.

`oozie job -oozie http://<url>/oozie -Doozie.wf.rerun.failnodes=true -rerun WFID`

Comment: To add, we are using CDH5.4 distribution.

Comment: I run into a similar issue today. I think that you can pick only one option and when you use it you cannot restart the same workflow with the other option. The reason is that workflow keeps stored configuration options. It still remember oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes. But when you add oozie.wf.rerun.skip.nodes it fails with the check that you can have only one. Solution could be maybe some feature request to rewrite those restart properties by the latest selected option.

Answer (score 9):

Everytime an oozie job is executed in a rerun mode, it will try to reuse the previous run's conifg file. you can however pass additional properties to it using -D option and thats how we pass oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes and oozie.wf.rerun.skip.nodes.

If you have execueted your job in rerun mode already once with `oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes=true` once, then in your next run you cannot use

```
oozie job -oozie http://<url>/oozie -Doozie.wf.rerun.skip.nodes=node1,node2 -rerun WFID
```

because when its trying to reuse config file, `oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes` property is already existing in its properties and that's when oozie tries to throw an error like you have faced.

Comment: Can you specify -Doozie.wf.rerun.failnodes=false on the second run, if you want to skip some nodes?

Comment: Note - We can only skip previously successful actions

Answer (score 1):

you could start the workflow from the beginning by giving  oozie.wf.rerun.failnodes=false property...thats what i do when i reran a job already, this is similar to skip node oozie.wf.rerun.skip.nodes=, but we cant skip anything

Comment: Could you include some code in your answer in order to improve it?